# MongoDB - Aggregation match and sort - very slow on empty match (with indexes)

Tags: mongodb

I building an application in PHP with MongoDB. The table I am having issues on has ~1million rows.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30
```

I use aggregation to select rows that match my criteria. After the matching stage I use sort to arrange the response elements but it takes 20 seconds to execute if after the matching stage I have an empty response.

I've tried to use unwind but and it fixed the the issue, but it raised another. If there are matching documents the query will become slow.

CASE 1:

```
db.getCollection("article_copy").aggregate([
    {$match: {'sections.related': ObjectId('5de3699c3019d0978901f355')}},
    {$sort: {_id: -1}}

])
```

The match stage will not match any documents and it takes 20s to execute. The aggregation with only the match (without sort) executes instantly as I do have an index on sections.related.

CASE 2:

```
db.getCollection("article_copy").aggregate([
    {$match: {'sections.related': ObjectId('5db3699c3019d0978901f255')}},
    {$sort: {_id: -1}}
])
```

In this case I do have matching documents and the aggregation is blazing fast (less than 0.03s).

Example of document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db1da921d88bc6ee50460be"), 
    "id" : NumberInt(2228550), 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    "sections" : [
        {
            "related" : ObjectId("5db3699c3019d0978901f255"), 
            "order" : NumberInt(1), 
            "type" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "related" : ObjectId("5db3699c3019d0978901f256"), 
            "order" : NumberInt(1), 
            "type" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    ],
}
```

Note: I do have idexes on:
- section.related

Indexes:

````
```/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "homeOrder" : 1
        },
        "name" : "homeOrder asc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "sections.order" : 1
        },
        "name" : "test",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "sections.related" : 1
        },
        "name" : "secrel_asc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "sections.related" : -1
        },
        "name" : "secrel_desc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "sections.order" : -1
        },
        "name" : "secord_desc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "sections.type" : 1
        },
        "name" : "type_acs",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : -1,
            "sections.related" : -1
        },
        "name" : "id_sec",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "author_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "auth_asc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "article_status" : 1
        },
        "name" : "art_stat_asc",
        "ns" : "dbTests.article_copy"
    }
]```
````

Comment: *"I do have idexes on: - section - section.related"* - Why do you have an index on `sections`? ( Also presuming that is a typo, if in fact you created indexes on the incorrect property names, then that is another issue ). This is just the property containing the whole array. If you have that specific index you should remove it. Using `'sections.related'` is just fine. You might in fact show the result of a `getIndexes()` on your collection, as you might have some things there you do not need.

Comment: Thanks for the observation! I removed it. It was there because of the previous version of the database. Do you have any ideea why it takes 20s to sort nothing? @NeilLunn Also, ```db.getCollection("sections").find({'sections.related': ObjectId('5de3699c3019d0978901f355')}).sort({_id: -1})
``` is blazing fast (0.03s)

Comment: It's not taking 20 seconds to "sort nothing", but on a large enough index it *could be* taking that amount of time *"looking for something"*. Notably this would a a multi-key index since it is on a property within an array. Now there also might be reasons for that, which is largely the reason I requested you include the list of indexes left present on the collection, as it might be some indication that the query planner is *"trying other things"* in order to obtain a match, and that is what *could* be taking time.

Comment: I might note here that I ran a few tests based on the description of the problem given so far, and for me this is something that does not reproduce. Both the selection of a value which should be in the index and with one that certainly is not. return equally as almost instantaneous. As noted, there could be other factors at play here, but not as currently described in the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've added the indexes in the question.

Comment: You have a lot of indexes on `"sections.related"`. These are all unnecessary and likely causing a problem. Drop them all and create one. Make sure you create the index in the foreground as well since this is the most efficient outcome. Indexing is still sadly the most misinterpreted and misunderstood concept with databases. Any more than 3 on a collection is generally wasting space and I/O and causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add a multiple index. Although I have separate indexes on _id and sections.related, only after I've create a multiple index with the both of them the query became efficiend.