# Skip mongo $sort in case of empty result after $match in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to understand how mongo aggregate pipeline execution works, for example, if I have a normal query like this:

```
collection.find({user_id: 1, shop_id : 1, deleted_at: {$eq: null}}).sort( { _id: -1 }).skip(0).limit(100)
```

all works fine and the empty result returned, but when I'm trying to use aggregate:

```
collections.aggregate([ 
  { $match: { user_id: 1, shop_id: 1, deleted_at: { $eq: null } } },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, 
  { $skip: 0 }, 
  { $limit: 100 }
])
```

it's loading forever... if I remove `{ $sort: { _id: -1 } }` from pipeline it's working as expected. Is it possible to tell mongo to skip sorting in case of an empty result?

NOTE: it seems like mongo omitting `$group` in case of empty `$match`, because on empty `$match` query like this:

```
aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: {"user_id": 5918725, "shop_id": 1775207, "$text": {"$search" : "API"}}
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "_id", 
          count: { 
              $sum: { 
                  $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$deleted_at", null ] }, 1, 0 ]  
              } 
          } 
      } 
  }
]);
```

will return empty result instead of count

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721530/mongodb-aggregation-match-and-sort-very-slow-on-empty-match-with-indexes

Comment: but why do non-aggregate query work fine and only aggregate query slow? I understand that index might help, but I want to understand why aggregation works like that, I thought if match returning empty array it should omit all next stages